# How to Vertical Align a img inside a horizontal ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a navigation working fine in my website, but, we decided to put the logo in the middle of it and now I can't vertical align it, I tried using `line-height` but it did not make the trick.

I put the code in the snippet, can someone give me a hand?

```css
nav > ul > li > a > img {
  width: 60px;
  }

nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  }

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  }

nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Wi-Fi_Logo.svg/1280px-Wi-Fi_Logo.svg.png" alt="logo"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How do you want the items to be aligned? Centered vertically?

Comment: I want to put the text in the same line as the "wifi" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block` by default is `vertical-align:baseline` so set it to `middle`,

same rule to `img`, so if you don't want to apply to `li` you can apply  to `img` instead

```css
nav > ul > li > a > img {
  width: 60px;
  /*vertical-align:middle - this would work here by itself too */
}
nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Wi-Fi_Logo.svg/1280px-Wi-Fi_Logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just vertically align the image, using the `vertical-align` property.

The value you want is most likely `middle`.

```css
nav > ul > li > a > img {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }

nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  }

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  }

nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Wi-Fi_Logo.svg/1280px-Wi-Fi_Logo.svg.png" alt="logo"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```